# Geometry Problem Concerning Altitudes and Medians

Tags: geometry

$M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$, and $T$ is the intersection of $\overline{BN}$ and $\overline{CM}$, as shown in the attached diagram. If $\overline{BN}\perp\overline{AC}$, $BN = 12$, and $AC = 14$, then find $CT$.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AVdV.png)

Comment: Can you prove that $\triangle TCN$ and $\triangle ABN$ are similar? You can get an answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

First, from the property of intersecting medians we can find $NT$:
$$
{NT\over BN}={1\over3}, \quad\mbox{ so } \quad
NT = {BN\over3} = {12\over3} = 4.
$$
Since $N$ is the midpoint of $AC$ we have $CN={1\over2}AC=7$.

By the Pythagorean theorem, from the right triangle $CNT$ we can find the hypotenuse $CT$:
$$
CT^2 = CN^2 + NT^2 = 7^2 + 4^2 = 65, \quad\mbox{ therefore } \quad
CT = \sqrt{65}.
$$
So the answer is $\sqrt{65}$.